# Inverse process of :keys destructuring: construct map from sequence

Tags: clojure

The more I write in Clojure, the more I come across the following sort of pattern:

```clj
(defn mapkeys [foo bar baz]
   {:foo foo, :bar bar, :baz baz})
```

*In a certain sense*, this looks like the inverse process that a destructuring like

```clj
(let [{:keys [foo bar baz]}] ... )
```

would achieve.

**Is there a "built-in" way in Clojure to achieve something similar to the above `mapkeys` (mapping name to keyword=>value) - perhaps for an arbitrary length list of names?**

Comment: Stack Overflow is perfectly happy for you to answer your own questions, but you should do so as an Answer (there's an Answer Your Question button below the existing answers), not as a footnote to your Question. I've rolled back your edit: you can recover its contents from the edit history in order to create your Answer.

Comment: For interest's sake out of a language comparison POV: I've worked quite a lot with JavaScript the last couple of months, and I was slightly pleased to find it allows something like `{a, b, c}` as a shortcut for `{a: a, b: b, c: c}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No such thing is built in, because it doesn't need to be. Unlike destructuring, which is fairly involved, constructing maps is very simple in Clojure, and so fancy ways of doing it are left for ordinary libraries. For example, I long ago wrote [`flatland.useful.map/keyed`](https://github.com/clj-commons/useful/blob/master/src/flatland/useful/map.clj#L6-L17), which mirrors the three modes of map destructuring:

```
(let [transforms {:keys keyword
                  :strs str
                  :syms identity}]
  (defmacro keyed
      "Create a map in which, for each symbol S in vars, (keyword S) is a
  key mapping to the value of S in the current scope. If passed an optional
  :strs or :syms first argument, use strings or symbols as the keys instead."
    ([vars] `(keyed :keys ~vars))
    ([key-type vars]
       (let [transform (comp (partial list `quote)
                             (transforms key-type))]
         (into {} (map (juxt transform identity) vars))))))
```

But if you only care about keywords, and don't demand a docstring, it could be much shorter:

```
(defmacro keyed [names]
  (into {}
        (for [n names]
          [(keyword n) n])))
```

Comment: Great, and chosen because first. For interest's sake I also added my independent thought process to the question (I did something similar to your second macro but filtered for only symbols).

Comment: I don't really understand the value of your added feature: what do you hope to get out of this? Since it's a macro, you will generally be writing its inputs by hand. Since a `1`, for example, makes no sense in this context, you can just omit it, rather than writing in some junk in order for it to be filtered.

Answer (score -1):

I find that I quite frequently want to either construct a map from individual values or destructure a map to retrieve individual values.  In the [Tupelo Library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) I have a handy [pair of functions](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.03.25/api/tupelo.core#vals-%3Emap) for this purpose that I use all the time:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [m {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}]
    (with-map-vals m [a b c]
      (spyx a)
      (spyx b)
      (spyx c)
      (spyx (vals->map a b c)))))
```

with result

```
; destructure a map into values
a => 1
b => 2
c => 3

; construct a map
(vals->map a b c) => {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

---

P.S.  Of course I know you can destructure with the `:keys` syntax, but it always seemed a bit non-intuitive to me.

Comment: As written this is a link-only answer. You include some code, but none of it is the important part, the answer to the actual question. If this link rots somehow, then having some test cases leftover in the Answer will be no use to anyone. Also, I continue to encourage you to disclose your ownership of Tupelo when you advertise it in an answer.